# Get the tax rate(s) from an order in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

I'm displaying my products in the cart without any taxes because I'm adding them afterwords to the subtotal sum in the cart. The problem is that I can't find a way to get the tax rate used for an order later on the **My Orders** page. So I'm looking for a way to get the tax rate used during the checkout for an order. The rate can be different depending on the country.

What I have is:

```
global $order;

$order->get_the_used_tax_rate_somehow();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the tax rate(s) from an order you will have **to get order "tax" item(s)**.

You will get [`WC_Order_Item_Tax`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Tax.html) protected Object(s) and you have to use the [dedicated available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Tax.html).

Sample code:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

// Loop through order tax items
foreach( $order->get_items('tax') as $item ){
    $name        = $item->get_name(); // Get rate code name (item title)
    $rate_code   = $item->get_rate_code(); // Get rate code
    $rate_label  = $item->get_label(); // Get label
    $rate_id     = $item->get_rate_id(); // Get rate Id
    $tax_total   = $item->get_tax_total(); // Get tax total amount (for this rate)
    $ship_total  = $item->get_shipping_tax_total(); // Get shipping tax total amount (for this rate)
    $is_compound = $item->is_compound(); // check if is compound (conditional)
    $compound    = $item->get_compound(); // Get compound
}
```

**Note:** An order can have multiple tax rates (items "tax").

---

You can also use some related [`WC_Abstract_Order`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html) methods on the `WC_Order` Object to get:

- Get the tax location for the order: `$order->get_tax_location()` *(array)*.
- Get all tax classes for items in the order: `$order->get_items_tax_classes()` *(array)*. *It will display an empty value for the "Standard" tax class*.

Comment: Thanks for your help Loic! That made it :) But now I've got another problem. Could you check if you already had this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862170/how-can-i-get-all-available-tax-rates-in-woocommerce/57862400#57862400