# How can I get all available tax rates in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently building a custom form. In this form I want to display the country select which is already present at the checkout.

This is my tax settings list:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<select class="country-select">
    <?php
    foreach ( WC_Tax::get_rates() as $rate ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $rate->tax_rate . '">' . $rate->country . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I'm expecting following options:

```
<option value="19">Deutschland</option>
<option value="20">Österreich</option>
```

The problem is that I don't get any results back from the `get_rates()` function. I've found no function which can return me the correct rates. Do you have any idea how I can get this done?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

```
$all_tax_rates = [];
$tax_classes = WC_Tax::get_tax_classes(); // Retrieve all tax classes.
if ( !in_array( '', $tax_classes ) ) { // Make sure "Standard rate" (empty class name) is present.
    array_unshift( $tax_classes, '' );
}
foreach ( $tax_classes as $tax_class ) { // For each tax class, get all rates.
    $taxes = WC_Tax::get_rates_for_tax_class( $tax_class );
    $all_tax_rates = array_merge( $all_tax_rates, $taxes );
}
```

**Explanation:**

As far as I know, you can only get a list of all tax rates given a specific `tax_class`, which is used to filter `woocommerce_tax_rates` table by `tax_rate_class` column (well, we can always query the database directly, but I'm assuming you want to solve the problem using functions provided by WooCommerce). Also, "Standard rates" have no `tax_class`, ie. `tax_rate_class` column is an empty string.

So if you want to get all tax rates per class, you need to use `WC_Tax::get_rates_for_tax_class( $tax_class )`. But if you really want all tax rates regardless of class, you need to get all tax classes first, then get all tax rates per class.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got tax rates configured, it's possible that they don't cover whatever user you're logged in as.

Try feeding the `$tax_class`, and `$customer` arguments to your `WC_Tax::get_rates` method! Specifically a customer and tax class that the Deutschland and/or Österreich rates from your example apply to!

Review the actual function definition [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Tax.html#485):

```
<?php

// class-wc-tax.php

class WC_Tax {
// ...
    /**
     * Get's an array of matching rates for a tax class.
     *
     * @param string $tax_class Tax class to get rates for.
     * @param object $customer Override the customer object to get their location.
     * @return  array
     */
    public static function get_rates( $tax_class = '', $customer = null ) {
        $tax_class         = sanitize_title( $tax_class );
        $location          = self::get_tax_location( $tax_class, $customer );
        $matched_tax_rates = array();

        if ( count( $location ) === 4 ) {
            list( $country, $state, $postcode, $city ) = $location;

            $matched_tax_rates = self::find_rates(
                array(
                    'country'   => $country,
                    'state'     => $state,
                    'postcode'  => $postcode,
                    'city'      => $city,
                    'tax_class' => $tax_class,
                )
            );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_matched_rates', $matched_tax_rates, $tax_class );
    }
}
```

Comment: No, just utilize it differently

Comment: Hey, @Mr.Jo - did you end up solving?